# xdotool random/more natural delay?

Tags: scripting, x11, testing, random

For automated testing of some applications, I would like to emulate the users behaviour. I know I can user the `xdotool type --delay` option, but I would like a more natural delay.

The easiest thing would be to add a random delay, but more advanced methods are also appreciated.

Is there such a option / utility?

Comment: In the title you say "random delay", but in the body you say "more natural delay". These terms seem too vague to give an indication of what you actually want. How are you defining "natural delay" here?

Comment: @ChrisDown Good feedback, thanks. Adjusted the question.

Comment: What sort of application: command line, web, non web X11?

Comment: With `xte` (from `xautomation`), you can insert arbitrary delays (including in between keypress and keyrelease events).